# A question on the parabola..

Tags: conic-sections

Consider the following lines

1. $x-y-1=0$
2. $x+y-5=0$
3. $y=4$

The line 1 is the axis of the parabola, the line 2 is the tangent at the vertex to the same parabola, and the line 3 is another tangent to the same parabola at some point $P$.

Now let a circle $C$ circumscribing the triangle formed by tangent and normal at the point $P$ and the axis of the parabola.

Then **how can I find the equation of the circle**?

I have tried and found that the vertex of this parabola is (3,2).
Need help....don't know how to proceed further....
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A question on parabola](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487536/a-question-on-parabola)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem does NOT ask you to find the equation of the parabola nor does this problem really have anything to do with a parabola, strictly speaking.  The problem asks you to find the circle passing through the three points of intersection of the lines y= x+ 1, y= 5- x, and y= 4.

What **are** those three points?  How do you find the equation of a circle passing through those points,

Answer (score 0):

If equation of axis, tangent at vertex and another tangent is given then it is possible to work out the equation by finding focus and directrix. I have solved a similar question in one of my videos. Pls have a look https://youtu.be/U9MTLxq8qFM